# Is multinomial logistic regression really the same as softmax regression

Tags: multinomial-logit, softmax

**Multinomial logistic regression** (MLR) is an extension of logistic regression for more than $2$ classes. The extension is made up by keeping linear boundaries between classes and using the class $K$ as pivot:
$$\log \frac{Pr(G=i)}{Pr(G=K)} = \beta_i x$$

Now since everything has to sum up to 1:

$$\sum_{i=1}^K Pr(G=i) = 1\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{K-1} e^{\beta_i x}Pr(G=K) +Pr(G=K) \Rightarrow Pr(G=K) = \frac{1}{1+\sum_{i=1}^{K-1} e^{\beta_i x}}$$

**Softmax** on the contrary assumes for all classes:

$$Pr(G=i)= \frac{1}{C}e^{\beta_i x}$$

where $C$ is a constant. Forcing to sum up to one:

$$C= \sum_{i=1}^K e^{\beta_ix}$$
so:
$$Pr(G=i)= \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^K e^{\beta_ix}}e^{\beta_i x}$$

Now here are the things that aren't clear to me:

- **How are they said to be the same if they do not even have the same parameters**? By using class $K$ as pivot, MLR does not have parameters $\beta_K$, while Softmax has.
- If they are the same, can someone prove to me?
- If they aren't the same, I assume the boundaries cannot be the same: are they at least similar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Softmax and logistic multinomial regression are indeed the same.

In your definition of the softmax link function, you can notice that the model is not well identified: if you add a constant vector to all the $\beta_i$, the probabilities will stay the same. To solve this issue, you need to specify a condition, a common one is $\beta_K = 0$ (which gives back logistic link function). But you can of course specify something else, like the sum of $\beta_i$ to be $0$ for example. Then the parameters of the softmax regression will be different from the parameters of the logistic regression, but there will be a one to one transform to go from one to another. Meaning that making inference with one model is equivalent.

Comment: `if you add a constant vector to all the , the probabilities will stay the same`: what do you mean?

Comment: If your replace $\beta_i$ by $\tilde{\beta}_i = \beta_i + \alpha$, then $Pr(G = i)$ is the same using $\beta_i$ of using $\tilde{\beta}_i$. Meaning that $\beta_i$ and $\tilde{\beta}_i$ would give the same model..